# Is there an automated way to create a temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather complex `SELECT` statement in a stored procedure that I am updating to insert the rows from the select into a temp table. To define the temp table, I need to know the data type of each every item selected.

Is there a easy way (a script maybe) that I can use to determine the data types and the temp table structure instead of going to each table's definition in the select to find out what it is?

PS: I can't use a Common table expression as I need to use this temp table several times within the proc

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: My question is about how to define the `#temp` table

Comment: @DotnetDude: That's the point. When you `SELECT INTO`, you do not need to predefine your table and its columns.

Comment: `SELECT INTO` will define it based on the source table.

Comment: Can I do a `SELECT INTO` with a table variable? I use table vars more than local temp tables.

Comment: Not with variables, no.  They need to be explicitly defined AFAIK.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion here about temp tables versus table variables.  You don't DECLARE temp tables, you just CREATE them.  If you are using DECLARE for your "temp" table then you are really talking about a table variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  blah
INTO
  #temp
FROM
  wibble
```

`blah` and `wibble` are not secret syntax.  Please replace these with your own SQL :)

Comment: My question is about a easy way to declare the `#temp` table. When I declare it, I need the data type of what the select returns. For a rather complex `SELECT` that selects from multiple tables, I need to open up each table definition to find out what the data type is.

Comment: @DotnetDude - This creates the table, without it being previously declared/created.  As you asked for :)  It is *not* `INSERT INTO #temp SELECT blah FROM wibble` which requires the table to already exist.

Comment: Can I do a `SELECT INTO` with a table variable declared using `DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE` ?

Comment: @DotnetDude - Unfortunately, not.  It only works with real tables or temporary tables.  :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: @Dems can't he use Dynamic SQL to do something like that?

Comment: @aF. - Only, I think, if the DynamicSQL reads the table definitions of the source tables for the query.  I can't think of a non-messy way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM TABLE1

All columns in TABLE 1 gets into your temp table now